IS this sol for ISL 2019 N7 correct?
The following problem is from the IMO shortlist 2019 N7 .
" Prove that there is a constant $c>0$ and infinitely many positive integers $n$ with the following property: there are infinitely many positive integers that cannot be expressed as the sum of fewer than $cn\log(n)$ pairwise coprime $n$th  powers."
Here is the proof I got which I am not so confident about, and would be glad if someone could check it :-
Solution: -
For a large $M$ pick $n=LCM(1,2,....,p_M-1)$ where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime. we show this works.
By chinese remainder theorom we know we for any $e_1,e_2,.....,e_M$
there exists infinitely many $L \equiv e_i$(mod $p_i^{k_i}$) where $k_i=1+$ exponent of $p_i$ in $n$
We prove for any such choice of $L$ if
$L=(a_1)^{n}+......+(a_k)^{n}$
Then
Lemma1 : the remainder when $k$ is divided by $p_i^{k_i}$ is $e_i$ or $e_i+1$
Observe $(a_i)^{n} \equiv 1$(mod $p_i^{k_i}$) exactly when $a_i$ is not divisible by $p_i$[otherwise its $0$] by eulers theorom . For $\phi{(p_i^{k_i})}=p_i^{k_i-1}(p_i-1)|n$ , so if all $a_i$ is not divisible by $p_i$ we know $L \equiv k$(mod $p_i^{k_i}$) so it works in that case , and if one of them is divisible by $p_i$ there is at max $1$ one such $a_i$[due to pairwise coprime] , so then $k \equiv L+1$(mod $p_i^{k_i}$)
, hence finsihing the proof of our lemma.
Lemma 2: For a suitable choice of $e_1,e_2,...,e_M$ the smallest $k$ which will satisfy the congruence relation will be atleast $\frac{n(p_1p_2....p_M)}{C^M}$ . for a constant $C$
The idea is to parition the residue class of $(p_i)^{k_i}$ into pairs of consequtive numbers  , that is like
$(0,1),(2,3),....,((p_i)^{k_i}-3,(p_i)^{k_i}-2)$ which is atleast $\frac{(p_i)^{k_i}-1}{2} >  \frac{(p_i)^{k_i}}{C}$ such pairs for a large enough constant $C$ . [if $p_i=2$ then the parition does not work like this its a bit different however that dosent affect the bounds]
Now as we choose any such $e_i$'s from the those disjoint pairs[such that $(e_i,e_{i}+1)$ becomes that pair] , we will end up with atleast $\frac{n(p_1p_2....p_M)}{C^M}$ positive distinct solutions[as for the pairs were disjoint no two solutions could be equal] , so one of solutions will be atleast $\frac{n(p_1p_2....p_M)}{C^M}$ , finsihing the proof of the lemma .
With that we prove the main problem Now we know $k \geq \frac{n(p_1p_2....p_M)}{C^M}$ infinitely often for a fixed $M$ .
It suffices to show
$\frac{n(p_1p_2....p_M)}{C^M} \geq \mathcal{O}(n log (n))$ for a large enough $M$
$\iff \frac{p_1p_2.....p_M}{C^M} \geq \mathcal{O}(log(n))$
as $n \leq p_M^{p_M}$ [this looks so cursed :P]
It suffices to show
$ \frac{p_1p_2....p_M}{C^M} \geq \mathcal{O}(p_M log(p_M))$
SO we can just show that
$e^{\frac{p_1p_2....p_M}{C^M}} \geq p_M^{p_M *C_2}$ for a suitable choice of $C_2$
or that $e^{\frac{p_1p_2....p_{M-1}}{C^{M-1}}} \geq p_M^{C_2}$  [$C_2C$ is just another constant so i just wrote it as $C_2$]
Its well know that $ p_i< 2^i$ for large $i$  a result that can be easily proved by bertands.
By that as $M$ grows larger eventually
$\Pi_{i=1}^{M-1} \frac{p_i}{C} \geq (p_M)^{T}$ for a large number $T$
and as $e^{x} \geq x$ for large enough $x$ and we are done.
Any suggestions on how this proof can be written in a better way is also appreciated.
Thank you for reading .

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

I would say the part where i set up the inequalities and and proof of lemma 2 because i dont think  other solutions did exactly did the same thing

Though honsetly speaking i specificly knew where i messed up , i wouldnt be asking in first place :P
